# How to access to the textFields of ResearchKit consent form?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, researchkit

When you create an `ORKConsentSignature` object and add it to an `ORKConsentReviewStep`, ResearchKit automatically presents a view that asks for the first name and last name.

[image]
Is there a way to grab access to these 2 textfields? Basically I want to add some custom `inputaccessoryview` to these textFields, therefore I need to be able to reference them. Thanks!